# react-testing-library material-ui slider

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, material-ui, react-testing-library

I am trying to create a test for material-ui slider. Able to find slider options but `fireEvent.click()` does not trigger `onChange` event. Example is in here: 
https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-y62ks

Answer (score 0):

I'm late to the party, but for some people.

Use `fireEvent.mouseDown(option1);` it should work, I tested it in codesanbox link.

For future people also want to test slider please see my answer:
[Testing a material ui slider with @testing-library/react](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58856094/testing-a-material-ui-slider-with-testing-library-react/62240633#62240633)

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you are testing MUI components, you must use userEvent, instead of fireEvent, because most MUI components do not use "standard" functions like `onClick` to trigger their events.

userEvent best simulates the user's action. You can import it from "@ testing-library / user-event".